# DataTable group and sum data

Tags: powershell, datatable

I have a Powershell DataTable with two columns, pobox [string] and pages [int].

Data:

```
pobox   pages   
7002        5
7002        2
7002       10
7004        1
7004        8
7006        2
7006        1
```

I am trying to group and sum the data like this

```
pobox   pages   
7002       17
7004        9
7006        3
```

I have tried countless combos with Group-Object, Select-Object.

```
    $dataTable | Group-Object ...
    $dataTable | Group-Object | Select-Object ...
```

But it seems completely impossible for me to find any solution that works.

In SQL it is very easy:

```
SELECT
  pobox,
  SUM(pages) AS pages
FROM pagecount
GROUP BY pobox;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with a hash table for storing sums.

```
$groupby = @{}
$dataTable | ForEach-Object { $groupby[$_.pobox] += [int]$_.pages }
$groupby | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Result:

```
Name Value
---- -----
7006 3
7004 9
7002 17
```

Comment: That was really nice. Using `$groupby[$_.pobox] += [int]$_.pages` to both add and, if the key  exists, update the key in the hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
$dat_grouped = $dat_table | Group-Object pobox | ForEach-Object 
{[PSCustomObject]@{pobox = $_.Name; pages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object pages -Sum).Sum}}

$dat_grouped | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: This works great. The code was missing a semicolon between **$_.Name** and **pages**. But that's a minor thing. The code `[PSCustomObject]@{pobox = $_.Name; pages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object pages -Sum).Sum}` is a bit abstract but I'll try to analyze it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks PGhere, glad to hear it was of some use.